# Gallery Refreshing in android

Tags: android, gallery

I am deleting the file from  Gallery in  my application .The file is deleted successfully but  after deletion the file  still showing in the Gallery  until i restart my device. 
I have tried different Solution like

> ```
>        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE,
>                Uri.fromFile(from.getParentFile()));
>           sendBroadcast(intent);
> ```

and  media Scanner

```
public class SingalmediaScaner implements MediaScannerConnectionClient {

private MediaScannerConnection mMs;
private File mFile;

public SingalmediaScaner(Context context, File f) {
    mFile = f;
    mMs = new MediaScannerConnection(context, this);
    mMs.connect();
}

@Override
public void onMediaScannerConnected() {
    mMs.scanFile(mFile.toString(), null);
}

@Override
public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
    mMs.disconnect();
}
```

and

```
private static void removeThumbnails(ContentResolver contentResolver,
        long photoId) {
    Cursor thumbnails = contentResolver.query(
            Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, null, Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID
                    + "=?", new String[] { String.valueOf(photoId) }, null);
    for (thumbnails.moveToFirst(); !thumbnails.isAfterLast(); thumbnails
            .moveToNext()) {

        long thumbnailId = thumbnails.getLong(thumbnails
            .getColumnIndex(Thumbnails._ID));
    String path = thumbnails.getString(thumbnails
            .getColumnIndex(Thumbnails.DATA));
    File file = new File(path);
    if (file.delete()) {

        contentResolver.delete(Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                Thumbnails._ID + "=?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(thumbnailId) });

    }

}
}
```

}

But none of above is working for me 
The file is deleted but the Gallery is not refreshing .
how i can refresh the Gallery without  restarting my device . 
or how i can refresh Gallery without Restarting my app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the following method.

```
private void deleteFormGallery(String filepath){
        String[] retCol = { MediaStore.Video.Media._ID };
        Cursor cur = application.getContentResolver().query(
            MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, retCol, 
            MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA + "='" + filepath + "'", null, null);

        Log.i(TAG, "::deleteFormGallery: count = " + cur.getCount());
        if (cur.getCount() == 0) {
            return;
        }
        cur.moveToFirst();
        int id = cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns._ID));       
        cur.close();

        Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, id);
        int rows = application.getContentResolver().delete(uri, null, null);        
        Log.i(TAG, "::deleteFormGallery: " + id + " deleted rows = "+rows);
    }
```

Comment: this method not refresh the 
Gallery after deletion ....Deleted item still showing  in gallery

Comment: I had the similar problem. After I deleted the file it's still shown in the gallery as a broken file. But in my case it's a video. You may need to tweak a bit. Also what does the logs say?

Comment: oh sorry ...MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI....solve my problem ../Thanks  Shashika

Answer (score 2):

Its because your Images are stored in memory card and yo need to refresh your memory card to see the changes reflected.

Use:
 sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://"
                            + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
context.sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri
                    .parse("file://"
                            + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the following code (which is also much like my code for creating a video which also tells the media system about file changes and correctly updates the Gallery):

```
private void deleteVideo(String videoUrl)
{
    File videoFile = new File(videoUrl);
    if (!videoFile.delete())
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to delete " + videoUrl);
    }
    else
    {
        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(mContext,new String[] { videoUrl }, null, new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() 
        {
            public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) 
            {
                Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":");
                Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> uri=" + uri);
            }
        });
    }
}
```